React Native read JSON object item always returns undefined
In this scenario I have a JSON object returned from a query like :
{"details": {"frequency": 2462, "data": "7839792384", "isExpensive": false}, "isConnected": true, "type": "item"}

stored in a variable myVar; and if I do console.log(myVar); I obtain all the object, so if I do console.log(myVar.isConnected); it returns true. But if i do console.log(myVar[0].data); it returns me undefined and it crashes... how can be managed this valid json object about data subitem?
Thanks in advance to all!
Cheers!

You need to select it from "details".
You are trying to select it like an array myVar[0] will work if you have:['something','otherThing']
This will select you the 'something'.
In you case you need to do mayVar.details.data or and it will do the job :)


Thanks @Zhivko , I thought it was to use [0] to access internal object....
